# Get record set from stored procedure using C++ ADODB CommandPtr::Execute()

Tags: c++, sql, adodb

I'm trying to get a recordset from a stored procedure using ADODB.
Stored procedures get executeed successfully (Doing everything written in the SP), but the recordset count is "-1".

Here is what I'm doing (stored procedure has no parameters):

```
hr = ptrCom.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command));
ptrCom->ActiveConnection = _connection;
ptrCom->CommandType = adCmdStoredProc;

ptrCom->CommandText = _bstr_t(_T("get_all_users"));

_variant_t  vtEmpty(DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);
ADODB::_RecordsetPtr record_set;
HRESULT normal_hr = ptrCom->raw_Execute(&vtEmpty, &vtEmpty, adCmdStoredProc, &record_set);

int cnt = record_set->RecordCount; // PROBLEM: cnt == -1 :-(
```

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just calling Execute?

```
ptrCom->Execute(NULL, NULL, ADODB::adCmdStoredProc);
```

returns _RecordSetPtr.

You might also want to try:
after you set the connection.

```
ptrCom->ActiveConnection->PutCursorLocation(ADODB::adUseClient);
```

Comment: The command "ptrCom->ActiveConnection->PutCursorLocation(ADODB::adUseClient)" solved it! :-) Thanks!